# All repositories in Docker registry get removed after docker daemon restart (docker-for-mac)

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-for-mac

I can successfully create a docker registry v2 service using:  `docker service create` then I push some if my images to it using docker push.
When I check the registry by curling `localhost:5000/v2/_catalog` I get all my pushed repositories. I even successfully create a stack using this registry.
The problem is whenever I restart docker (directory or by restarting my mac) all my repositories get removed from registry. I checked on linux but it did not have any issue.
Am I doing something wrong? I just wanted to send this question here before opening any issue in Docker for mac github repo. 
I'm using Docker for mac `version 17.09.0 CE (build 19611)`

Comment: Can you provide the full "docker service create" command that you are using? You may be storing the images inside the container instead of using a --mount. That means any time the service's task stops, the container's write layer will be gone with it. Use a mount for your persistent data.

Comment: @programmerq Which path in the registry conteiner should I mount my fs to in order for its images to be stored on my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for registry data to persist after service (containers) restart you should mount your filesystem to it using `--mount /path/in/my/system:/var/lib/registry` in your `docker service create` command.